# ArrayList strange behaviour

Tags: java, arraylist

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my code

latest_songs,top_songs and hit_songs are arraylist.song() is a static method in Parseurl where i fetch the json array.it working fine & return proper data.

```
    latest_Songs = ParseUrl.song(url1);
      Log.i("ring,latest=", latest_Songs.toString());
    top_Songs = ParseUrl.song(url2);
      Log.i("ring,top=", top_Songs.toString());
    hit_Songs = ParseUrl.song(url3);
      Log.i("ring,hits=", hit_Songs.toString());
```

it works fine when i run latest_songs and top_songs.problem is with hit_songs.as i write this in my project both arraylist(latest_songs and top_songs) data overrided with hits_songs.where i am doing wrong.

this is ParseUrl from where i retrieve data in each arraylist

```
public class ParseUrl {
static ArrayList<String> songs_List = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> songs_Names = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> songs_Urls = new ArrayList<String>();

static File tempFiles;
File ringtones;

public static ArrayList<String> song(String url) {
    songs_Names.clear();
    songs_Urls.clear();
    JSONObject json = JsonParse.getSongfromUrl(url);

    try {
        JSONArray latestSongs = json.getJSONArray("ringtones");
        for (int count = 0; count < latestSongs.length(); count++) {
            JSONObject song = latestSongs.getJSONObject(count);
            songs_List.add(song.toString());
            JSONArray name = song.names();
            songs_Names.add(name.toString());
            String songUrl = name.toString();
            String URL = songUrl.substring(2, songUrl.lastIndexOf("\""));
            songs_Urls.add(song.getString(URL));
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return songs_Names;

}
```

Comment: where can i get rest of the songs i mean the code?

Comment: So we have to guess the code , how you wrote ?

Comment: I'm not sure I have the clairvoyance to be able to provide you with an answer...

Comment: how on earth are we suppose to know what those `***_Songs` mean? And what they are supposed to do?

Comment: I guess they're ArrayList objects

Comment: And I guess they contain songs! XD

Comment: You are assigning same value all the three lists it seems, it is not overridding :-)

Comment: @Renjith: it is overriding.

Comment: @gbl...according to the code you posted, it is certainly not overriding, since you are using same url value.It the url value is different, then code is missing.

Comment: @Renjith:please see my code.it clearly mentioned url1,url2,url3.

Comment: @gbl...initially it was url only.Anyways, with this code no one can tell you what is wrong.You must post additional code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arraylist is a static variable inside your class.So there is only one arraylist in memory.Each time you call the song method , you are modifying the same list.That means your latest_songs,top_songs,hit_songs, all will be pointing to same list.That is the reason your list is getting over ridden.
Try creating a list inside your method and return it rather than going for static variables.

Comment: :i tried..still not working

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: :i have changed the code.now it's working.thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing the `url` value anywhere?
Because you are assigning `ParseUrl.song(url)` to all the three array lists. Unless `url` is changed somewhere, all three array lists will have the same value since `ParseUrl.song(url)` will give the same result.

Comment: :yes, i am using different url for everey parsing.

Comment: :when i remove hits_songs=ParseUrl.song(url3).it work properly.

Comment: we need rest of the code. This doesnt help